# How do you load a file (.csv) into a Beeware/Briefcase application?

Tags: kivy, kivy-language, beeware

I am using kivy as the GUI and Briefcase as a packaging utility. My .kv file is in the appname/project/src/projectName/resources folder. I also need a .csv file, in the same folder, and want to use pandas with it. I have no problem with importing the packages (I added them to the .toml file). I can't use the full path because when I package the app, the path will be different on each computer. Using relative paths to the app.py file does not work, giving me a file not found error. Is there a way to read a file using a relative path (maybe the source parameter in the .toml file)?

```
kv = Builder.load_file('resources/builder.kv')
df = pd.read_csv('resources/chemdata.csv')

class ChemApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.icon = 'resources/elemental.ico'
        return kv
```

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered and solved a similar problem with Briefcase, even though I was using BeeWare's Toga GUI.

In my case, the main Python file `app.py` had to access a database file `resources/data.csv`. In the constructor of the class where I create a main window in `app.py`, I added the following lines (The import line wasn't there, but included here for clarification):

```
from pathlib import Path

self.resources_folder = Path(__file__).joinpath("../resources").resolve()
self.db_filepath = self.resources_folder.joinpath("data.csv")
```

Then I used `self.db_filepath` to successfully open the CSV file on my phone.

`__file__` returns the path to the current file on whatever platform or device.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, to get a relative path you can use self.paths.app. For example:

```
with open(self.paths.app / 'resources/help_file.htm', 'r') as file:
        html_content = file.read()
```